# Notepad++ regex command for searching two following lines

Tags: notepad++, regex

I want to search a file for a word in a line and another word in the line after that
For example i want to find a line which contains `75 37` and i want the line after that to contain `8B 45 FC`
Is there any regular expression for that ?

Here's an small chunk of the file to see what i really need, the file has more than 9 million lines

```
MyFile.exe+A9554- C7 45 FC A6190000     - mov [ebp-04],000019A6 { 6566 }
MyFile.exe+A955B- 0FB7 CE               - movzx ecx,si
MyFile.exe+A955E- 33 D2                 - xor edx,edx
MyFile.exe+A9560- 33 C1                 - xor eax,ecx
MyFile.exe+A9562- C1 EE 10              - shr esi,10 { 16 }
MyFile.exe+A9565- 33 F0                 - xor esi,eax
MyFile.exe+A9567- 8B 45 FC              - mov eax,[ebp-04]
MyFile.exe+A956A- 35 DF050000           - xor eax,000005DF { 1503 }
MyFile.exe+A956F- C1 E6 10              - shl esi,10 { 16 }
MyFile.exe+A9572- 89 45 FC              - mov [ebp-04],eax
MyFile.exe+A9575- 0B F1                 - or esi,ecx
MyFile.exe+A9577- 8B 45 FC              - mov eax,[ebp-04]
MyFile.exe+A957A- 35 790C0000           - xor eax,00000C79 { 3193 }
```

Comment: Do you need it to select the whole line for processing, mark those lines or just point out each instance to you?

Comment: @Worthwelle Sorry but i couldn't understand your question, i have updated my question to clarify what i need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your sample text to actually include the information you're searching for for this example.

The following Regular Expression should show you want you need. `(75 37).*\R.*(8B 45 FC)`

You can see this in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/MqBpQN/3).

Make sure that `. matches newline` is not checked.

[image]

To break this down:

1. `(75 37)` searches for the first instance
2. `.*\R.*` passes the newline character
3. `(8B 45 FC)` searches for the second instance

Comment: `\R` is simpler than `\r?\n` for the same result.

Comment: @Toto Thanks! I've updated the answer to use that.